# How to use grid in angular.js

Tags: angularjs

I need to implement following functionality in angular grid.

Paging.
Filtering.
Sorting column wise.

Please suggest me which angular js grid should I use.

Comment: I use angular-grid - http://www.angulargrid.com/example.html

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend [Angular UI Grid](http://ui-grid.info/). Does all you asked for and is part of the Angular UI suite. One of the better data grids I've worked with.

Comment: Ah, are you using NuGet with Visual Studio? I'm not certain. If so you would want to lookup 'Angular UI' as it comes in the full Angular UI suite. I can't remember if that is automatically bundled with Microsoft's repo.